# Is there a way to use only the word result of most_similar function of gensim?

Tags: trigonometry, gensim, word2vec, similarity

I am trying to use the most similar function of gensim but the results came in as a list that is let's say a=(word, cosine similarity). However I can't retrieve the word by a[0].Is there a way to access the word itself? I need to use it as an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ranked list of results returned by `most_similar()` is a *list* where each item is a tuple of a word and its similarity value.

After...

```
sims = model.wv.most_similar(my_word)
top_word = sims[0][0]
```

...`top_word` would have the word most-similar to `my_word`.

Comment: You missed one bracet but it totally worked, thank you.